# Getting the date on which an event in a time-series (e.g., the minimum value) occurs

Tags: time-series

I want to get the time in a time series that a particular event  (e.g., the minimum value) occurs. The approach I take below seems clumsy. Is there a better way?

```
ts = TimeSeries[FinancialData["GE", "Jan. 1, 2007"]];
DateListPlot[ts]
```

[image]

```
6.66 = Min[ts]
p = Position[ts["Values"], Min[ts]][[1, 1]];
ts["DatePath"][[p]]

{DateObject[{2009, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0.}], 6.66}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A few other versions, the first one being the cleanest in a sense that it combines operation of finding the minimum and extracting the date.

```
MinimalBy[Normal[ts], Last]

Cases[Normal[ts], {_, Min[ts]}]

Cases[ts["DatePath"], {_, Min[ts]}]

Extract[Normal[ts], Position[ts["Values"], Min[ts]]]
```

Comment: Thanks, Vitaliy. I appreciate the different examples.  I didn't know about Extract.

Answer (score 0):

Will find nearest value to zero and the corresponding date:

`Nearest[ts["DatePath"], {0, 0},  DistanceFunction -> (#2[[2]] - #1[[2]]] &)]`

`{{Fri 15 May 2020 00:00:00GMT+2,$ 43.92}}`